# Oatmeal used in apple crisp topping

Tags: dessert, oats

The recipe I am looking at for Apple Crisp by Ina Garten calls for 1 cup of oatmeal.  It doesn't say prepared oatmeal, or rolled oats, just "Oatmeal".

Is the recipe asking for 1 cup of prepared oatmeal (rolled oats + water)?  1 cup of rolled oats and then prepared into oatmeal?

Or is it something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's definitely asking for rolled oats, not prepared oats. It's just like oatmeal cookies.

It's up to you whether you use normal rolled oats, quick-cooking, or instant. I use normal in my crumbles, but you might choose quick or instant if you think the normal retain too much texture. Personal preference! They'll all work, though, so you can just use what you've got on hand.

(When I do oatmeal for breakfast, I prepare normal rolled oats as if they were instant - just add boiling water. I like some texture.)

And while I'm at it, general advice: crumble topping is something you can easily do without a recipe, just throwing in the ingredients until it holds together a bit, but is nice and crumbly. So don't worry too much about exactness here. It'll come out great.

Answer (score 2):

I would use quick-cooking oats (do not prepare with water).